# What could be causing high cpu in google spanner databases? (unresponsive table)

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-spanner

I'm facing an issue where 2 out of 10 spanner databases are showing a high CPU usage (above 40%) whereas the others are around %1 each, with almost identical or more data.

I notice one of our tables has become "unresponsive" no queries work against it. We shutdown all apps that connect to those dbs, and we also deleted all current sessions using gcloud sessions list and then gcloud session delete.

However the table is still unresponsive. A simple select like select id from mytable where name = 'test' is not responding (when tested from an app, and also from gcloud web interface), it only happens with that table, which has only a few columns with normal data and no more than 2000 records. We identified the query that could have been the source of the problem, however the table seems to be locked (only count(*) without any where clause works).

I was wondering if there is any way to "unlock" the table, kill those "transactions" that might be causing the issue, or restart those specific spanner databases, or in the worst case scenario restarting the spanner instance.

I have seen the monitoring high cpu documentation, but even if we can identify the cpu is high, we don't really know how to restart or make it back to normal before reviewing the query/ies that could have caused the issue (if that was the case).

Comment: Are you still having issues this morning? Could this be a google issue?

Comment: Hello, yes, kind of. We had to create a new data base from one of our backups, after performing a batch schema update to the table that has more than 1000 columns, consulting other tables in the system started to fail again in the new database, which I believe confirms (99%) this schema updates are causing the issue somehow. What seems like a bug is that it is not the table that's being altered the one where the selects stopped working but other "random" tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High CPU can be caused by user initiated queries, from [different types of operations](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/investigate-cpu-utilization#what_is_a_user-initiated_operation). It is important to notice that your instance is where you allocate resources to be used by the underlying Cloud Spanner databases. This means, that if all of your databases are in the same instance and if some of your databases are hogging the CPU, all your other databases will struggle.

In terms of a locked table, I would be very surprised if a deadlock is the problem here, since Spanner mitigates those issues using "wound-wait" algorithm. What I suspect might be happening is that a long time is necessary to perform the query in that table and it times out. It would be nice to investigate a bit more on your problem:

- How long did you wait for your query on the problematic table (before you deemed to be stuck)? It might be a problem where your query just takes long and you are timing out before getting the results. It might be a problem where there are hotspots in your table and transactions are getting aborted often, preventing you from getting results.
- What error did you get when performing the query on the table? The error code can tell you more about what might be happening.
- Have you tried doing a [stale read](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reads#perform-stale-read) on the table to see if any data is returned? If lock contention is the problem, this should succeed and return results faster for you. Thus, you can further investigate the lock usage with the statistics table (as shown below).
- Inspect query statistics: you can list the [queries with the highest CPU usage](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/query-statistics), find the [average latency for a query](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/query-statistics#sql-latency) and find out the [queries that timeout the most](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/query-statistics#listing_the_queries_that_timeout_the_most). There is much more you can do, as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/query-statistics). You can also view the [query statistics in cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/view-query-statistics-in-console). What I would verify is, by reducing the overall CPU, does your query come back without any issues? You might need more resources if so. Or you might need to reduce hotspots in your database.
- Inspect Lock statistics: you can investigate lock conflicts in your rows and tables. I think that an interesting query for your problem would be [Discovering which row keys and columns had long lock wait times during the selected period](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/lock-statistics#discovering_which_row_keys_and_columns_had_long_lock_wait_times_during_the_selected_period). You can then see if your query is reading those row keys and columns and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time Thiago,

We executed the query from the web interface, we waited for over an hour. We have run queries against that table before with no problem, and it responds in fraction of a second. I mean it has less than 2000 records and it is simple data, no queries work, not even: select count(*) from where col_a = 'X', or select count(*) from where col_b = 'Y'. Right now there are no active sessions, and we shutdown all apps that connect to it for more than 2 days, and the metrics does match that.

Comment: We got no error from google web client, it just showed the spinning icon. I'm trying the gcloud command line now to see if I get back any error (right now it's been over 10min and no answer yet).

I haven't tried the stale read, will do.

We have inspected query statistics and the lock table and I think we found some (which are not optimized at all) that we need to look at (very high latency) which actually are executed against that table and we will try to fix them.

Comment: However as I said, now it has been 2 days sine we haven't executed any query against that table, actually not against any db since everything was shutdown.  The thing is, and despite all above points, no select is currently working against that table in particular and the cpu is still very high (according to the metrics this are low priority system tasks).

This is happening in our dev environment, if this happens in prod right now we wouldn't know what to do to make it back to normal (to make the table work again and lower the cpu, even with all apps down).

Comment: In dev, a few minutes ago we triggered a backup (and this is only now, no backups or any other processes have run against any dbs in the past days).  With the idea of deleting the db and restoring it to see if we can use table and if the cpu goes down. This is just so the developer can get back to work, but this is something we can't afford to do in prod if a similar issue occurs.

Comment: By any chance do you happen to have around 1000 columns in some of these tables and do you happen to be dropping and creating columns on the fly?

Comment: @ThiagoNunes Could this be a google related issue? We have experienced some spanner slow downs/timeouts on DML operations in the last 24 hours. Also what would be the affect of dropping and creating columns and the 1000 column table?

Comment: @ThiagoNunes yes as a matter of fact one of our tables is about 1006 columns (awful I know)! And we did update that table recently, and we do remove and add columns to that table often I would say. However, that's not the table that's not responding. 

BTW, as an update, we dropped the affected table (the one that's not responding, not the one with 1000+ columns), created it again, and it still didn't respond.

Comment: @jpaa89 Google's support / engineering team has been trying to get in touch with you (through email / LinkedIn). Could you check one of those for the best course of action for this matter? Thanks!

Comment: We got a support ticket opened (case number 28656432) @ThiagoNunes and got a message in my linked in profile which I have answered, if you want to check the case I'm happy to send you the link

Comment: The case number is  28656432, Max (CTO from the company) is following the case as well, thank you and gcloud team for the help!